# How can I fix this launchfile?

Tags: roslaunch, gscam, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dear ROS community!

I've started learning ROS a few months ago. Currently I'm trying to create my first launchfile that starts gscam and image_view packages to open a camera and visualize the video stream. I made a launch file, however, gscam and image_view cannot get connected. Gscam node is launching properly, but not the image_view one; it seems that it is not receiving the parameter. If I launch image_view manually ($rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/image_raw) everything works fine and I can visualize the video stream from my camera. How can I fix my launch file? Thank you!

```
    <launch>
<node pkg="gscam" type="gscam" name="gscam01">
<env name="GSCAM_CONFIG" value="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace" />
</node>

<node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="image_view01">
<param name="image" type="string" value="/camera/image_raw" />
</node>
```

SOLUTION:

```
launch>
<node pkg="gscam" type="gscam" name="gscam01">
<env name="GSCAM_CONFIG" value="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=30/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace" />
</node>

<node pkg="image_view" type="image_view" name="image_view01">
<remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192891/how-can-i-fix-this-launchfile?/) by [diegomex](https://answers.ros.org/users/20224/diegomex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The input to image_view is a topic, not a parameter. (the command-line usage here can be a little confusing).

Try using the `<remap>` tag:

```
<remap from="image" to="/camera/image_raw"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [diegomex](https://answers.ros.org/users/20224/diegomex/) on 2014-09-18**:
Thank you very much, this worked perfectly!